# std::async too many arguments

Tags: c++, asynchronous, arguments, future

Ok so I'm trying to use std::future in a project but the std::async i'm using with it keep telling me that there's too many arguments. I tried to see if I didn't misunderstood the template but nothing wrong came to me... Here's the call:

```
QVector<MyMesh::Point> N1;
QVector<MyMesh::Point> N2;
future<QVector<MyMesh::Point>> FN1 = async(launch::async, rangeSearch, &mesh, vit->idx(), diagBoundBox*0.02);
future<QVector<MyMesh::Point>> FN2 = async(launch::async, rangeSearch, &mesh, vit->idx(), diagBoundBox*0.02*2);
N1 = FN1.get();
N2 = FN2.get();
```

also the rangeSearch method used:

```
QVector<MyMesh::Point> rangeSearch(MyMesh *_mesh, int pid, float range);
```

See anything wrong?

EDIT: Here's a minimal reproducible example, sorry about the first one.

```
#include <future>

class Class
{
public:

    void A();
    int F(int a, int b, int c);
};

int Class::F(int a, int b, int c){
    return a+b+c;
}

void Class::A(){
    int N1;
    int N2;
    std::future<int> FN1 = std::async(std::launch::async, F, 1, 2, 3);
    std::future<int> FN2 = std::async(std::launch::async, F, 1, 2, 3);
    N1 = FN1.get();
    N2 = FN2.get();
}

int main()
{
    Class O;
    O.A();
}
```

Also the error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Class::A()’:
main.cpp:18:69: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int Class::F(int, int, int)’
     std::future<int> FN1 = std::async(std::launch::async, F, 1, 2, 3);
                                                                     ^
main.cpp:11:5: note: declared here
 int Class::F(int a, int b, int c){
     ^~~~~
main.cpp:19:69: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int Class::F(int, int, int)’
     std::future<int> FN2 = std::async(std::launch::async, F, 1, 2, 3);
                                                                     ^
main.cpp:11:5: note: declared here
 int Class::F(int a, int b, int c){
     ^~~~~
```

Comment: if you make it into a [mcve] and remove the irrelevant `QT`  classes it'll be easier to help.

Comment: Edited the post, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what you're asking so i'll say it's supposed to use it's own instance (although it shouldn't really matter in term of what it does, it could use any Class::F i guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here isn't really with the number of arguments you've passed. It's with the nature of the argument--specifically, with trying to pass a member function directly to `std::async`.

The easiest way to deal with this is almost certainly going to be to call the member function via a lambda expression:

```
#include <future>

class Class
{
public:
    void A();
    int F(int a, int b, int c);
};

int Class::F(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}

void Class::A()
{
    int N1;
    int N2;
    std::future<int> FN1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](int a, int b, int c) {
        return F(a, b, c); }, 1, 2, 3);
    std::future<int> FN2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](int a, int b, int c) {
        return F(a, b, c);}, 1, 2, 3);

    N1 = FN1.get();
    N2 = FN2.get();
}

int main()
{
    Class O;
    O.A();
}
```

Comment: I saw something like that, and it does seem to work (although it gives another error, and a lenghty one, but totally unrelated I suppose).

Comment: Edited the OG post

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in the code. First, to create a pointer-to-member-function, the syntax is `&Class::F`. Second, when you're using a pointer-to-member-function you need an object to apply it to. So the correct call (inside the member function `Class::A`) is

```
std::future<int> FN1 =
    std::async(std::launch::async, &Class::F, this, 1, 2, 3);
```

`std::async` assumes that a pointer-to-member-function in its argument list will be followed by a pointer or reference to the object that the member function should be applied to.